Mixed logit model with panel data
I am running a logit panel data model. I need the model to accommodate fixed effects for the geographical unit (id) and random effects for time (year).
Below is some sample data. outcome is the binary outcome and the other two variables are controls.
df <- data.frame(outcome= replicate(1,sample(0:1,1000,rep=TRUE)),
                 id= rep(c(1:20), rep=50),
                 year= rep(c(1:50), each=20),
                 temperature= replicate(1,sample(30:80,1000,rep=TRUE)),
                 unemployment= replicate(1,sample(0:22,1000,rep=TRUE)))


I tried running this pglm model with my real data and it takes too long. My real life data has around 2500 geographical units (counties) and 10 time units (years).
library(pglm)

model  <- pglm(outcome ~ temperature + unemployment + as.factor(id), 
data=df, family=binomial('logit'), index=c("id", "year"), 
model="random", effect="time")

Thank you
